# onTouchListener Action_Down not working

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm animating a `View` that shows if i slide up, and hide if i slide down.
The problem is that only work  when sliding up. If i slide down, the view move along with my finger but when i release the touch, it goes up again.

Here is the code that i use for the animation & slide.

```
 v.setY(480);
 v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

 v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(event);

                if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
                    v.animate().translationY(480);
                    return true;

                } else if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    v.animate().translationY(0);
                    return true;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

What am i missing?

Comment: visit this link may help you https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Gestures-and-Touch-Events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN don't mean direction.

ACTION_DOWN means an event when you have just touched the screen.
ACTION_UP means an event when you have just released your finger.